# identifying the forward slash

Tags: regex, perl

Suppose I have 3 variables.

```
my $val1 = './f1/abc.txt'; #f1 is the folder where abc.txt resides.

my $val2 = './f1/def.txt';

my $val3 = 'gh.txt';
```

I am facing an issue while reading the './f1/' part.

```
if ($val1 =~ m/^a.*\.txt$/ or  $val2 =~ m/^d.*\.txt$/) { print $val3; }
```

this doesn't work with the folder name. Please help.

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with forward slashes.  It has to do with you incorrectly using the `^` anchor.  `^` means "beginning of the string".  You are asking Perl if `$val` matches: "beginning of string, a, 0 or more of any character, period, txt, end of string".  It doesn't.  The `a` in $val1 is not adjacent to the beginning of the string, it is in the middle of the string.  Same thing for `$val2` - the `d` does not come at the beginning of the string.  Remove the `^` anchors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the forward slashes in "./f1/" with this escape sequence:

```
\/
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I was just using a double forward slash (\//)while scripting. Thanks for your help.